# Merge Mysite in Hybrid Solution

Tags: sharepoint-online, my-site, hybrid-solution, merge

A customer has an on premise SharePoint Server (2013) Farm with multiple web applications/site collections serving 15,000 users – each with a mysite.

The customer has also moved all collaboration site collections to Office 365/SharePoint Online to extend collaboration with external users. However, they have mysite in the cloud as well which makes it hard for the users not recognizing their new mysite. Some have (unfortunately) already started adding content and social feeds to their cloud mysite.

So my customer would like to know **How can we merge Mysite in this Hybrid Solution?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a yes version of the answer for this question at present: http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/74400.aspx

This tool says that it will allow you to migrate all your content: http://www.metavistech.com/category/tools-office-365

then in the meantime, you could do the following, as you migrate the content:

In central admin, on premises, change the location of your mysite host to the online location:  Application management > user profile service app > my site settings > My Site Host Location

This will redirect them to the Online location

And, turn off the ability for the user to create a mysite, via the user permissions of the user profile service, for the on premises

Comment: It was expected that this was a no go. I like your suggestion on how to move future content to the right location. +1 and bounty!